# Getting AverageRating and TotalReviews in its Reviews Response Group

Tags: api, amazon-web-services, ads

I am trying to get `AverageRating` and `TotalReviews` attributes from Product Advertising API for books, but Amazon Web Service (AWS) return "0" in a response.

I am using following **web service** in my project:

http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2010-11-01/AWSECommerceService.wsdl

**Response Groups:**

```
request.ResponseGroup = new string[] { "ItemAttributes", "Reviews", "Images" };
```

Can any one guide me how can I access above mentioned parameters.

Answer (score 0):

On November 8, 2010 the Reviews response group of the Product Advertising API will no longer return customer reviews content and instead will return a link to customer reviews content hosted on Amazon.com.So you won't be able to fetch back the AverageRating and Totalreviews.

Amazon API latest documentation:

http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/

Looks like you can't get sellerfeedback from the new API:

Product Advertising API Change Details
The following changes will take effect on 11/1/2011:

Seller Operations: The SellerLookup, SellerListingLookup and SellerListingSearch operations will be deprecated. All requests for these operations will be rejected with a corresponding error message.